# Needed: Algebra question to answer walkthrough

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following question is asked:

Multiply out:

$$3a(b+2c)-b(a-c)$$

The solution given:

$$2a(b+3c)+cb\quad\mbox{ OR }\quad 2ab+c(6a+b).$$

Could you please walk me through how they got to the solution.

Comment: I don't understand why either of those expressions would constitute "multiplying out". They just look like alternate arrangements. I would have said that the expression was $3ab+6ac-ba+bc=2ab+6ac+bc$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
3a(b+2c)-b(a-c) &= 3ab+6ac-ab+bc 
\\&= 2ab+6ac+bc
\end{align}

If you factorize out $2a$ from the first two terms:
$$2ab+6ac+bc=2a(b+3c)+bc$$

If you factorize out $c$ from the last two terms

$$2ab+6ac+bc = 2ab+c(6a+b) $$

Remark:

Personally I agree with @lulu that the solution for "multiplying out" should be just $2ab+6ac+bc$.